# Algebraic independence via the Jacobian

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, polynomials, commutative-algebra

I have seen being mentioned that algebraic independence of polynomials can be tested by the so called **Jacobian Criterion** (Apparently one takes the Jacobian matrix of these polynomials and inspects the rank of the matrix (or the rank of its minors)). Where can i find the precise statement and its proof?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/41535/how-to-show-a-set-of-polynomials-is-algebraically-independent

Comment: @user26857: I am aware of that post. However, the proof given in the comments is beyond my understanding. I was wondering if some more basic proof is possible, or if someone can translate it into commutative algebra.

Comment: My understanding was that $x^2$ and $y^2$ were algebraicly independent, even though the jacobian can be 0. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a combinatorial (!!!) proof see Theorem 2.2 from [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S019566988371022X).

Another reference seems to be S. Lefschetz, *Algebraic Geometry*, 1953, Ch. I, 11.4.

Comment: Very nice. I even understood the abstract, although it is not in English.